# error en extraer dato a Column::make() con query en laravel/livewire tables

Tags: laravel-livewire, livewire, laravel-10

Sucede que estoy usando Laravel Livewire Tables y al efectuar el proceso de mostrar la columna con el nombre del cliente, no me deja ponerla y me genera error.

Así tengo los modelos y las relaciones

Modelo de Projectos

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable =[
        'project_name',
        'clients_id_client',
        'status',
        'date_creation',
        'last_evaluation',
    ];

    //Relación uno a muchos inversa con clientes
    public function client(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }
    //Uno a muchos con Juicios, un proyecto, puede tener muchos juicios
    public function judments(){
        return $this->hasMany(Judment::class);
    }
    //Uno a muchos con Juicios, un proyecto, puede tener muchos juicios
    public function evaluatedFragances(){
        return $this->hasMany(EvaluatedFragance::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo de clients

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable=[
        'client_name',
        'contac_number',
        'client_agent'
    ];
    
    public function projects(){
        return $this->hasMany(Project::class);
    }
}
```

y así tengo el componente de tabla que he creado usando el Builder para hacer el inner join

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\DataTableComponent;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\Views\Column;
use App\Models\Project;
use App\Models\Client;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\Views\Columns\BooleanColumn;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\Views\Columns\ImageColumn;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\Views\Filters\SelectFilter;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\Views\Filters\MultiSelectFilter;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\Views\Filters\DateFilter;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLiveWireTables\Traits\WithSearch;
use Rappasoft\LaravelLivewireTables\DataTransferObjects\DebuggableData;

class ProjectsTable extends DataTableComponent
{

    //protected $model = Project::class;
    
    public function configure(): void
    {
        $this->setPrimaryKey('id');
        $this->setPerPageAccepted([5, 10, 25]);
        $this->setSearchLive();
        $this->setEagerLoadAllRelationsStatus(true);
        $this->setEmptyMessage('No se ha encontrado el registro');
        $this->setDebugStatus(true);
    }

    public function columns(): array
    {
        return [
            Column::make("Id", "id_project")
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable(),
            Column::make("Proyecto", "project_name")
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable(),
                Column::make("Cliente","client.name")
                ->eagerLoadRelations()
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable(),
            Column::make("Fecha creación", "date_creation")
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable(),
            Column::make("Última evaluación", "last_evaluation")
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable(),
            Column::make("Estatus", "status")
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable(),
        ];
    }

    public function builder(): Builder
    {
        return Project::query()
            ->select(
                'projects.id_project',
                'projects.project_name',
                'projects.status',
                'projects.date_creation',
                'projects.last_evaluation',
                'clients.client_name',
                'projects.clients_id_client'
            )->join('clients', 'projects.clients_id_client', '=', 'clients.id_client');
    }

}
```

El problema está cuando intento llamar a clients.client_name como client_name, allí es donde me arroja errores y me aparece el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco me puedan dar una ayuda.